# Keydown fired an incrementing number of times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a gallery and I'm having a bug with the `keydown` event (strangely only on Windows, not on Mac using the same browsers).

When I click on a thumb the slideshow opens and the images are ready to be seen. I enabled the images sliding through the arrow keys also. What's strange is that if I close the slideshow div and I re-open it (without any page refresh), if I try to navigate with the keyboard arrows it will skip from two to two images (1-3-5-7, etc.). And the "skipping number" increments as many times I close and open again the slideshow.

The function I use to navigate through the images through the keyboard keys is the same used when the "screen arrows" are clicked but, in this second case, everything works great. It's like if the keydown event has a cache or something like that.

Here's the whole `imgBrowsing()` function:

```
var imgBrowsing = function () {
    function prevNext(move) {
        /*
         * @move    { string: "prev" / "next" }
         */
        var prevCurrNext_obj = {
            'venus-img-wrap-prev':      $('.venus-img-wrap-prev'),
            'venus-img-wrap-current':   $('.venus-img-wrap-current'),
            'venus-img-wrap-next':      $('.venus-img-wrap-next')
        };

        if (move == "prev") {
            /* ***** Current img id re-definition ***** */
            (current_img_id >= 1)
                ? --current_img_id
                : current_img_id = images_length - 1;

            /* ***** PREV-CURRENT-NEXT classes re-attribution ***** */
            $.each(prevCurrNext_obj, function (class_name, jQuery_obj) {
                var b;
                (jQuery_obj.prev(venusImgWrap).length)
                    ? b = jQuery_obj.prev(venusImgWrap)
                    : b = $(venusImgWrap).last();
                b.addClass(class_name);
                jQuery_obj.removeClass(class_name);
            });
        } else if (move == "next") {
            /* ***** Current img id re-definition ***** */
            (current_img_id + 1 < images_length)
                ? ++current_img_id
                : current_img_id = 0;                           // = the first element inside the array-object 'images'
            /* ***** PREV-CURRENT-NEXT classes re-attribution ***** */
            $.each(prevCurrNext_obj, function (class_name, jQuery_obj) {
                var b;
                (jQuery_obj.next(venusImgWrap).length)
                    ? b = jQuery_obj.next(venusImgWrap)
                    : b = $(venusImgWrap).first();
                b.addClass(class_name);
                jQuery_obj.removeClass(class_name);
            });
        }

        venusDivFilling();
    }

    /* ***** KEYDOWN pression event ***** */
    $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
        switch (e.which) {
            case 39:            // right
                prevNext("next");
                break;
            case 37:            // left
                prevNext("prev");
                break;
            case 27:            // ESC
                venusDivRemove();
                break;

            default: return;    // exits this handler for other keys
        }
        e.preventDefault();     // prevents the default action (scroll / move caret)
    });

    /* ***** ARROWS click event ***** */
    $(venusImgBrowse).click(function () {
        prevNext($(this).data('venus-direction'));
    });

    /* ***** SWIPE event ***** */
};
```

Comment: That's just because the function is being called twice, when you've opened it twice on the same page. You need to make the function inside private

Comment: Assign `$(document).on("keydown"...` only once, or use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method to remove the event handler on modal close. Otherwise, if you open it 3rd time, you will go 1-4-7...

Comment: @skobaljic I didn't immediately realized I was actually binding the event twice and it totally makes sense now. Thanks for the `.off()` tip, I used that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because keydown is bound to body everytime you open the image viewer.

If you unbind keydown from body when the image div gets closed then you will no longer have this issue.

```
$("body").unbind().on("keydown")
```

---

[**EDIT**] As the official documentation says: *As of jQuery 3.0, [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) has been deprecated. It was superseded by the [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.*

```
$(document).off('keydown');
```

Comment: Linear explication, thanks Lissy! As I answered to @skobaljic I didn't immediately realized I was actually binding the event twice to `document`. I'm gonna mark your answer as the accepted one but I actually used the [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) as @skobaljic and jQuery suggest, instead of the deprecated (from 3.0) [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)